# Resources for building a Visual Studio plug-in?

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I'd like to build a pretty simple plug-in for Visual Studio, but I don't really know how this has to be done.  Is this doable in (non-managed) C++?

I'd like to know what resources you'd recommend me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried, so I don't know about doing it in C++, but this website has loads of information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

DevExpress has a *free* plug-in called [**DXCore**](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) which provides some nice abstractions upon which to then build other plug-ins...you might look into that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to do it in unmanaged code? DevExpress has a nice free library to develop visual studio plugins but it's managed. This is what they use to develop Refactor and coderush

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/

It seems the underlying API is kind of messy. As far as I know this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be this tutorial:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/AddIns11292005015631AM/AddIns.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [DXCore](http://www.devexpress.com/dxcore/) from [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) is a wonderful library for basing all sorts of [plugins](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/). Feel free to drop by the [IDE Tools Forums](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=18) and more specifically the [DXCore plugin forum](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/181.aspx) and ask for any help you might need. :)

I'm not so sure about unmanaged C++ but I know for certain that the DXCore supports Plugin creation in **any managed** language.

Answer (score 0):

Found this MSDN tutorial: [Creating Add-ins Using Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa699351%28VS.60%29.aspx). Thanks Matt.

Comment: old stuff. Visual Studio 6.0. That's even pre .net.